# Translation of the song "Land der dunklen Wälder"

Tags: translation, poetry

First of all, I hope it's not verboten to post [Ostpreußen's anthem](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostpreu%C3%9Fenlied) here.  Lately, I've been fascinated with this region's history (where my dad's best friend's mom was born), and this song has become a bit of an ear worm.

But I can't quite figure out what some of the words mean, and I haven't been able to find a full English translation *anywhere*.

Below are excerpts of the anthem I find difficult to translate (full text can unfortunately not be published due to copyright):

> Über Ackerbreiten
>       streicht der Vogelzug
>   ...
>      Elche stehn und lauschen
>       in die Ewigkeit
>
> Heimat wohlgeborgen
>   ...
>   blühe heut und morgen
>     unterm Friedensdom

To the best of my (limited) knowledge, this means:

> Land of dark forests
>       And crystal lakes
>       Over wide fields
>       Clear miracle goes
>
> Strong farmers stride
>       Behind horse and plow
>       **Over broad fields** *(lit. "acres")*
>       Stretches the migration *[of birds]*
>
> Day has dawned
>       Over lagoon and bog
>       Light has started
>       Rising in the east
>
> And the seas roar
>       The song of time
>       Elk stand and listen
>       **Into the ages** *(or "eternity")*
>
> **Homeland is well** *(or "probably") safe*
>       Between beach and stream
>       Flourish today and tomorrow
>       **In peace** *(lit. "under peacedom")*

In addition to these the following also confuse me:

1. What is "lichte Wunder gehn"?  "A clear miracle goes?"  "A light miracle goes?"  Is this an idiom?
2. What is "wohlgeborgen"?

Comment: The text is still copyrighted in many countries, until end of 2015 in all EU member states at least (possibly until 2038 if text and tune are considered one work). In the U.S., if copyright has been properly renewed, it may be copyrighted until about 1925; if not renewed, copyright in the U.S. has expired. Long story short, I'm not sure it's a good idea to include the full text here.

Comment: Removed parts of the anthem but left the translation.

Comment: @chirlu: who holds such a copyright? Wouldn't it be free stuff since the people involved have been dead for over 70 years?

Comment: @Emanuel: That's the point, they _haven't_ been dead for over 70 years. The lyricist died in 1945, the composer in 1968.

Comment: @chirlu: oh wow... I expected the period to be longer ago :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"licht" is obsolete as an adjective, but, exactly as you might expect, it used to mean simply "bright".

"Wohlgeborgen" is an inflected, compounded form of "wohl" (well) and "bergen". The classical sense of "bergen" is "protect" (and it can mean either through *concealment* or through *physical cover*).